# Anyone with experience using "Sansin Purity-Glacier"?

Tags: finishing

My local lumber store stocks and sells the Sansin line of finishes. I am planning to finish a maple countertop soon, and want a hard, durable finish that maintains the "whiteness" of the maple without the amber/yellow that I'd probably get from an oil-based polyurethane.

Sansin Glacier bills itself as just that but I haven't been able to find very many reviews through google, youtube, or otherwise. Has anyone tried this product?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. You would most definitely get an ambering with any oil-based poly on maple, although it tends to be less than with some other oil finishes. We don't have a lot of members providing Answers here, but maybe someone will have tried this product (although TBH I'm not sure how much value one additional anecdotal account would actually be). Anyway, just to mention something you might not be aware of — the maple itself will change colour over time, even under a water-clear finish. All pale woods darken naturally in some way, due primarily to light exposure.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to do some testing on some scraps of _your_ wood, as different pieces of the same species will finish differently. You can then post a self-answer (acceptable and even encouraged) describing your experience.

Answer (score 2):

We purchased the Arctic Clear (Purity Glacier) to treat 150 year old barn board for our kitchen cupboards; based on the fact Sansin claims it does not change color. I was surprised that it met what it claimed. We did not lose the silver grey patina. Sealing the wood darkens it minimally, but definitely no yellowing or change of color. Very happy with the results.